# c++ python 3 binding

Tags: c++, python

I am trying to bind python3 in C++.

When using this:

```
Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);
```

it gives this error:

```
error C2664: 'Py_SetProgramName' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char *' to 'wchar_t *'
```

Even though that's how the [documentation example](http://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html#the-module-s-method-table-and-initialization-function) shows to do it.

I also tried this:

```
Py_SetProgramName((wchar_t*)argv[0]);
```

But apparently that's the [wrong way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18246869/230623) to do it.

**So how do I fix this, and is there any other good resources on binding Python 3 in C++?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following:

```
wchar_t progname[FILENAME_MAX + 1];
mbstowcs(progname, argv[0], strlen(argv[0]) + 1);
Py_SetProgramName(progname);
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/mbstowcs/

Comment: MAXPATHLEN is undefined, I hard-coded it to 255 which allows me to compile. It appears to work though just like my 'wrong' solution I have no way to test it just yet. +1

Comment: Insert `#include <sys/param.h>` if you are using Unix.

Comment: @Brae, I can't find MAXPATHLEN equivalent in Windows. Use `#define MAXPATHLEN 1024`.

Comment: Ok, though I will probably leave it at 255 to be safe - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265769/maximum-filename-length-in-ntfs-windows-xp-and-windows-vista

Comment: @Brae, I replaced `MAXPATHLEN` with `FILENAME_MAX`. It does not require header. (not tested in Windows).

Comment: @Brae, According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y075fy39.aspx), it seems to be supported in Windows.

Comment: `FILENAME_MAX` is ISO C and C++. The Microsoft specific equivalent is `MAX_PATH`.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: be warned mbstowcs is a real source of trouble of some platforms. One random example would be android api 19. Python3.7+ has now integrated official workarounds and unicode coercion see PEP 538/540.

Comment: @PmpP., Thank you for the info.

Answer (score 4):

The official way of converting from char to wchar_t is now :

```
wchar_t *program = Py_DecodeLocale(argv[0], NULL);
Py_SetProgramName(program);
```

on a side note mbstowcs is not reliable on some platforms.

A quite good example of using python2/3 with c++ would be Panda3D. a c++ game engine scripted with python, that also provides a c++ module builder.

Comment: sorry but i don't see any answer for "is there any other good resources on binding Python 3 in C++",  correcting wrongs like mbstowcs use is 4 months old ( python3.7+ ) and imho important for newcomers. also embedding python in C++ is not very well supported so question has no age.

Comment: not saying you cant add to it, its just funny to me that its so old

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074776/how-to-convert-char-array-to-wchar-t-array)

The example documentation for the Python 3 API appears to have not been upgraded from Python 2 - the example you show is one of them (I have reported some of the others).

I have found no good documentation in this area.  Even the new (Python 3) editions of well-known Python books either cover this subject sparsely or have code errors (usually because the code comes from Py2).

Comment: That's a pain, thanks for the link, it looks very similar to falsetru's answer.