# Cannot convert ‘char**’ to ‘wchar_t**’

Tags: c, char, wchar-t, python-bindings

The code excerpt:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){  
    PySys_SetArgv(argc, argv);
```

produces error message

> error: cannot convert ‘char**’ to ‘wchar_t**’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘void PySys_SetArgv(int, wchar_t**)’

How do I convert `argv`?

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032080/how-to-convert-char-to-wchar-t

Comment: ‘wchar_t' is part of both?

Comment: And both have an `int` type, as much as Python and Java do! But a solution will be different for each language!

Comment: Ok, I am learning :) will change to c...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This API is part of python 3.0 and above and in my knowledge, there's no *easy* way to get this done. However, I think, you can try converting the `argv` to a `w_char **` and then call `PySys_SetArgv()`. [`mbstowcs()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/mbstowcs/) may come handy in this case.

For example, some pseudo-code (not tested) will look like

```
wchar_t **changed_argv;

changed_argv = malloc((argc)* sizeof*changed_argv);

for (int i = 0; i < argc, i++)
{
    changed_argv[i] = malloc(strlen(argv[i]) + 1);
    mbstowcs(changed_argv[i], argv[i], strlen(argv[i]) + 1);
}
```

Comment: @Olaf That's why I mentioned a pseudo-code. It is basically about the idea primarily. I think this can be considered as answer, because this is most likely to solve the issue in the question, isn't it? I'm not at all, knowledgeable about C++, just some basics....

Comment: I do not blame you actually. OP should just pick one language. The `malloc` problem alone makes a common solution - well - "complicated". That's why I actually downvoted the question.

Answer (score 3):

You could look into whether your compiler supports [wmain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438049/what-is-the-difference-between-wmain-and-main). If so, you can replace `main` with:

```
int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])
{  
    PySys_SetArgv(argc, argv);
```

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the following link:

[how to convert char array to wchar_t array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074776/how-to-convert-char-array-to-wchar-t-array)

You can write a conversion routine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace System;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char *orig = "Hello, World!";
    cout << orig << " (char *)" << endl;

    // Convert to a wchar_t*
    size_t origsize = strlen(orig) + 1;
    const size_t newsize = 100;
    size_t convertedChars = 0;
    wchar_t wcstring[newsize];
    mbstowcs_s(&convertedChars, wcstring, origsize, orig, _TRUNCATE);
    wcscat_s(wcstring, L" (wchar_t *)");
    wcout << wcstring << endl;
}
```