# cannot convert 'const char*' to 'LPCWSTR {aka const wchar_t*}'

Tags: c++, qt, char, type-conversion, wchar-t

I'm getting an error in my C++ code that I can't quite make sense of. The stripped down code bits are here:

```
RS232Handle=OpenRS232("COM1", 9600);

HANDLE OpenRS232(const char* ComName, DWORD BaudRate)
{
    ComHandle=CreateFile(ComName, GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error: cannot convert 'const char*' to 'LPCWSTR {aka const wchar_t*}' for argument '1' to 'void* CreateFileW(LPCWSTR, DWORD, DWORD, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, DWORD, DWORD, HANDLE)'
     ComHandle=CreateFile(ComName, GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
```

The code was taken from VS code and I am now using Qt creator.

How can I fix this issue? Thanks!

Comment: `const char *` and `const wchar_t *` are not the same and not implicitly convertible.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The Windows [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) function is actually a macro that expands to one of:

- `CreateFileA`, which takes a file path of type `const char*`
- `CreateFileW`, which takes a file path of type `const wchar_t*`.

(The same is true for most of the functions in the Windows API that take a string.)

You're declaring the parameter `const char* ComName`, but apparently compiling with `UNICODE` defined, so it's calling the `W` version of the function.  There's no automatic conversion from `const wchar_t*` to `const char*`, hence the error.

Your options are to:

1. Change the function parameter to a UTF-16 (`const wchar_t*`) string.
2. Keep the `char*` parameter, but have your function explicitly convert it to a UTF-16 string with a function like [MultiByteToWideChar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072(v=vs.85).aspx).
3. Explicitly call `CreateFileA` instead of `CreateFile`.
4. Compile your program without `UNICODE`, so that the macros expand to the `A` versions by default.
5. Kidnap a prominent Microsoft developer and force him to read [UTF-8 Everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/) until he agrees to have Windows fully support UTF-8 as an “ANSI” code page, thus freeing Windows developers everywhere from this wide-character stuff.

**Edit:** I don't know if a kidnapping was involved, but Windows 10 1903 finally added support [for UTF-8 as an ANSI code page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page).

Comment: #5 isn't a distinct option, it just lets #2, #3, and #4 work when the string contains extended characters.

Comment: Changing the Character Set in Visual C++ did the trick for me...

Answer (score 8):

There are many ways of fixing this

1. Open the project properties, General/Character Set.  This will be set to either Unicode or Multi byte character set.  If you wish to use char* change from Unicode to MBCS.  This will convert CreateFile to CreateFileW if Unicode is specified and CreateFileA if MBCS is specified.
2. Enclose all strings in _T() eg _T("COM1").  What this does is to compile the string as a char* if MBCS is specified, wchar_t if unicode is specified
3. Force all strings to be wide strings by prefixing with L eg L"COM1"

Note that in some error handling routine the strings are specifically MBCS

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
RS232Handle=OpenRS232(L"COM1", 9600);

HANDLE OpenRS232(const wchar_t* ComName, DWORD BaudRate)
{
    ComHandle=CreateFileW(ComName, GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
}
```

On Windows the wchar_t type is used to represent characters in UTF-16 encoding.  This is what the Windows kernel uses internally and therefore modern versions of Visual C++ default to Unicode functions. If you insist on using the ANSI functions instead (thus going back to your original code), remove the `L`-prefix from the string "COM1" and change the call from `CreateFileW` to `CreateFileA`.

Most Windows API functions that deal with strings have both a `W` and an `A` version; the only exception that I am aware of is the function [`GetProcAddress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx) which *always* takes an ANSI string regardless of whether you're working with ANSI or Unicode in your project.

Comment: If your datatype is hardcoded as `wchar_t*`, use `CreateFileW`.  The `CreateFile` function macro should only be used together with the `TCHAR` or `LPCTSTR` type macros.

Comment: @BenVoigt Expanded my answer

Answer (score 2):

`const char*` and `const wchar_t*` are two different types with no implicit conversion between them. Therefore, you need to perform the conversion to before passing the value on to the `CreateFile` function. Take a look at this answer for a possible conversion approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3074785/6710751

Alternatively you might just use the `CreateFileA` function instead of `CreateFile`, as was suggested by Ben Voigt.

Comment: Or just call `CreateFileA` which will do the conversion for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've added this to the answer.