# I am getting this error message - a value of type "const char *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type"LPCWSTR"

Tags: c++, lpcwstr

These are the lines of code that are causing the error:

```
    WndClass.lpszClassName = "WinProg";
```

and

```
hWindow = CreateWindow("WinProg", "Window", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, 400, 400, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

I don't know how to "fix" this error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cannot convert 'const char\*' to 'LPCWSTR {aka const wchar\_t\*}'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40641572/cannot-convert-const-char-to-lpcwstr-aka-const-wchar-t)

Answer (score 2):

When building for UNICODE, prefix string literals like this:

`L"wide string literal"`

and they will be `wchar_t`, not `char`.

In your case, it should be:

```
WndClass.lpszClassName = L"WinProg"
```

Comment: *Technically*, it *should* be using the `TEXT()` macro instead, eg: `WndClass.lpszClassName = TEXT("WinProg");` (same with the string parameters of `CreateWindow()`) since he is calling the `TCHAR`-based `RegisterClass()`+`CreateWindow()` macros, instead of directly calling the Unicode `RegisterClassW()`+`CreateWindowW()` functions.