# C++ Builder (Rad Studio 10.2): [bcc32 Error] E2357 Reference initialized with 'char', needs lvalue of type 'wchar_t'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++builder, vcl, lvalue

I'm trying to compile an old Turbo C++ package with C++ Builder compiler (Rad Studio 10.2).

During this, I got error:
`[bcc32 Error]  E2357 Reference initialized with 'char', needs lvalue of type 'wchar_t'`
connected with this block of code:

```
void __fastcall TRsEdit::KeyPress(char &Key)
{

   bool ok = true;

   if ( ! IsNumber(Key))
   {

      if (! IsTabOrReturn(Key))
         ok = false;

   }

   if (!ok && !ComponentState.Contains(csDesigning) )
     Key = 0;

   TEdit::KeyPress(Key); 
}
```

Error occurs for line: `TEdit::KeyPress(Key)`

This procedure is declared in Vcl.StdCtrl.hpp file as:

```
DYNAMIC void __fastcall KeyPress(System::WideChar &Key);
```

Does anyone know how deal with this problem?

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074776/how-to-convert-char-array-to-wchar-t-array

Comment: The RTL and VCL switched to Unicode in 2009. `System::Char` and `System::String` were changed from `char`/`AnsiString` to `wchar_t`/`UnicodeString`. As such, `TRsEdit::KeyPress(char &Key)` should be updated to either `TRsEdit::KeyPress(WideChar &Key)` or `TRsEdit::KeyPress(Char &Key)` to match the new signature of `TEdit::KeyPress()`

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works for TRsEdit::KeyPress(WideChar &Key).